# NIC/Network performance tuning in CentOS

Tags: performance, network-programming, udp, kernel, packet-loss

We run an UDP based app server in which we are expecting high traffic. So I am in the process of tuning our NIC to achieve  best performance with high throughput (compromising  a little of latency).

For testing, I am using the 2 machines with the below configurations.

**Machine Details**

```
CPU : 40core
Threads per core: 2
Cores per socket : 2
NUMA node : 2
Model name : Intel(R) Xenon(R ) CPU E5-2630v4
CPU MHx: 2199.841
NUMA 0: 0-9, 20-29
NUMA 1: 10-19, 30-39
RAM: 128GB
```

**NIC Details:**

```
Driver: ixgbe
Version : 4.4.0-k-rh7.3
10G capable
```

While doing a simple load test I observed that the receiving rate (packets/sec) is not same as the sender.

(Observing the stats through SAR command)
**Sender:  (sar -n UDP 1)**
**odgm/s**

```
1098825.00
1097993.00
1098103.00
```

**Receiver:**
**Idgm/s**

```
622742.00
616321.00
649075.00
```

From the above, you can see the difference between the sender and receiver datagram packets.

**Packet loss Observation:**

Ethtool, netstat, sar - Observed stats in all these tools and no packet drop reported here.

**Currently tuned:**( with this tuning I was able to achieve max of 630k avg/ sec in receiver end)

```
IRQBALANCE : disabled
CPU affinity   : manually distributed (each rx-tx queue / CPU)
Interrupt coalesce : rx-usecs 15
Flow control : on
Ring Buffer : rx 512
Rx Queue : 40
rmem_default = 16777216
rmem_max = 16777216
```

Rest all are default values
Edit1: I changed to busy poll - 50 and was able to achieve better throughout but not consistent.

1. Why there is a difference in rate between the sender and receiver ? What all other NIC/OS params that can be tuned to achieve equal throughput rate as sender?
2. One strange thing that I observe using ethtool is this param “*rx_no_dma_resources*” keeps incrementing rapidly during the test.. Does it ring anything?
3. Even though I disabled “irqbalance” in /proc/interrupts and /proc/net/softnet_stat there is no equal distribution of interrupts.
4. Overall my ultimate goal is to achieve the best throughput with minimum packet loss.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have answers to all your questions and also not specific centos. It is my previous experience with the interrupt based packet receiving.

As you mentioned that you need best throughput, interrupt based method is not a way to go. In one of the project we did,  We identified that interrupt based method has huge overhead due to context switch hence huge number of packets are discarded. I suggest you to use polling with low polling frequency. Although it causes more execution overhead. You will be able to achieve better throughput.

I hope my suggestion will be useful for your project.

Comment: Yes , indeed I changed to polling busy poll (50) and was able to achieve better throughout but not consistent. For ex , I was able to achieve around 720k and abruptly dropping to 600k , 580k. This is strange because I observe no drops or error except for rma-no-resources and fdir mismatch keeps increasing ...